# Macro used to replace arguments inside another macro in C

Tags: c, macros, microcontroller, avr

Hi I am having a problem with using C macros and was wondering if anybody could help:

```
#define A7 PORTA,7
#define SET_BIT(x,y) x=x|(1<<y)
```

I am trying to set up Macros such that in the main code, I can just type

```
SET_BIT(A7); to set the 7th bit of A7
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'SET_BIT'
error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the way you wanted by using an intermediate macro which will expand the parameter to two parameters separated by a coma.

```
#define A7 PORTA,7
#define SET_BIT_INNER(x,y) x=(x)|(1<<(y))
#define SET_BIT(x) SET_BIT_INNER(x)

SET_BIT(A7);
```

As valter said, don't forget the parenthesis around every parameters used in a macro.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define A7 PORTA
#define SET_BIT(x,y) (x)=(x)|(1<<(y))  

SET_BIT(A7,7);
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I understand that but the original poster said: to set the 7th bit of **A7**. So the best way should propably be: `#define A PORTA and then SET_BIT(A,7);`